# Is there any way to silence the robot companion?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

The incessant repetition of "I was just wondering what I could do to please you!" stopped being cute the 3rd time. I couldn't use the pet to heal, because it seemed to be bugged to repeat that phrase every second or two. It's so close to the door of my ship that it chimes off every time I enter/exit.

I'd delete the thing permanently if it would Just Shut Up. I don't suppose someone has figured out a way to replace a file or something similar?

Comment: His constant offers of a foot massage are... *creepy* at best.

Comment: Dev forum comments suggested one of the patches will reduce companion chatter some. But still no option to toggle it off, or adjust it yourself.

Comment: Man, that C2-N2 talks more than C-3PO.

Comment: There's always [tag:murder]...

Comment: I like the other companions, but I would seriously murder C2-N2 even if it pushed me from Light II to Dark III.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At th moment the only way to mute the incessant ramblings of *that* protocol droid is to mute "voices" through the sounds options menu.

Comment: I wondered, does that count for cutscenes, as well? or just ambient chatter?

Answer (score 1):

As of 1.2 (I think) the frequency with which the ship droid speaks has been greatly reduced.  I still hate it when he does, but that's more of a conditioned response than anything since it is no longer incessant.